# Is there an alternative for Nuget?

Tags: nuget

Is it possible to download files for VS 2012 without Nuget and install necessary files to VS 2012?

I do not have an access to the internet on my PC so I find other ways to download necessary items and install this files in VS 2012 without Nuget:). Nevertheless, I would like to have templates in VS 2012 like I have templates as if I would download these items by Nuget.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247121.aspx

Comment: How are you planning to download anything if you don't have internet access?

Comment: files downloaded are not always templates. They may be other type of files. How to be eith them? For example, some libraries.

Comment: I can download from another Pc and bring necessary file to my PC by CD.

Comment: Possible duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14894864/how-to-download-a-nuget-package-without-nuget-exe-or-visual-studio-extension-fr/14895173#14895173.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're able to bring downloaded stuff to your no-internet machine, then you can setup a local nuget feed on that machine:

1. On the internet-enabled machine, go [here](http://nuget.codeplex.com/releases/view/59864) and download the Nuget
   Package explorer.
2. Fire up this tool once downloaded, then choose "Open package from
   online feed"
3. Search for the package you want, and hit ok, the package will open
   up.
4. Go to file -> save as -> and choose a location to save the .nupkg
   file to.
5. Take whatever .nupkg files you download, and transfer them to a sensible place on your other no-internet machine
6. In VS, open tools -> library package manager -> package manager settings -> package sources
7. Type in a new name for your local feed, such as "Local Feed"
8. Put in the source of the feed, ie the local directory where you placed the .nupkg files
9. Click the "Add" button

Now when you manage nuget packages, you can select your local feed and add packages from there, exactly as though they were from the web.

Comment: How to add project templates? For example SQL Server Compact 4.0

Comment: New address for Nuget Package Explore is: http://npe.codeplex.com/downloads/get/clickOnce/NuGetPackageExplorer.application